# How to set an image as a background on WebView's onReceivedError method ?

Tags: android, android-webview

Is it possible to set an image as a `WebView`'s background on `onReceivedError()` method?

Does it makes any sense to you guys?

Comment: you should load a html page with that image instead of setting image as background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
webView.setBackgroundColor(0);
webView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.test2);
```

Comment: webView.setBackgroundColor(0); what does this meant for?

Comment: Its working but its showing both error page and my image. any idea to not to show the default page? btw u missing visible attribute add it also to ur answer

Comment: `webView.setBackgroundColor(0);` this sets the backgroundColor to transparent, it is same as 0x00000000. You need to reset/clear the webview in `onReceivedError()` method to view the background image